# Does this discrete probability distribution have a name?

Tags: probability-distributions, terminology

I was wondering whether the probability distribution

> $$P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda}{(1+\lambda)^{k+1}}, \quad k= 0, 1, 2, \dotsc,$$

where $\lambda$ is a fixed positive number, has a name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). There is some slight terminology ambiguity explained in the wikipedia article.  The customary parameter is $p = \lambda/(1+\lambda)$. (And not $1/(1+\lambda)$, as Peter Foreman points out.)

Comment: The value of $1-p$ is $\frac1{1+\lambda}$, not $p=\frac{\lambda}{1+\lambda}$

Comment: @PeterForeman Thanks for the catch!